# Countable and Uncountable sets of a sequence

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Please help!

**Question:**
If you try to mark all the points on the real line that correspond to rational numbers, and thereby draw a “picture” of $\mathbb{Q}$, you will find yourself marking so many points that they will seem to fill up most of the line. (For instance if you were to mark all the points corresponding to rationals with denominator 1,000,000, the line would appear virtually completely marked.) The purpose of this exercise is to show that this impression is dramatically false.
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, its members can be listed:
$\mathbb{Q}$ = $\{q_1, q_2, q_3, . . .\}$

(a) Surround $q_1$ by an interval $I_1$ of length $1/2$. (The precise location of
$I_1$ is not important.) Then surround $q_2$ by an interval $I_2$ of length $1/2^2 = 1/4$. Continue in this manner, covering each $q_n$ by an interval $I_n$ of length $1/2^n$. (Some of the intervals will overlap, and that is acceptable.) What is the “total” of the lengths of all these intervals, and what does this tell you about the size of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a geometric object?

(b) Now let $\epsilon$ denote a small positive number (the smaller the better), and again cover the rationals by intervals; but this time cover each $q_n$ by an interval of length $\epsilon/2^n$. Again find the “total” of the lengths of all these intervals. Now what do you conclude about the size of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a geometric object?

**Answer:** I'm thinking of a geometric sequence for a: $1/2+ 1/4+ ...+ 1/2^n$. The sum would be $S_n = q_1/1-r = (1/2) / (1-1/2) = 1$. But what does this tell you about the size of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a geometric object?

For b, The sum would be $S_n = q_1/1-r = (\epsilon/2) / (1-1/2) = \epsilon$. Again, I'm confused about the size. What does it mean by "the size ... as a geometric object?".

EDIT: Then, with the result above, answer the following question:

Imagine that you are going to throw a dart at the xy-plane; in this fantasy include the assumption that the tip of the dart will hit exactly one point $P$. Peer pressure demands that you bet on one of the following three possibilities:

(a) Neither coordinate of $P$ will be rational. (My guess!)

(b) Exactly one coordinate of $P$ will be rational.

(c) Both coordinates of $P$ will be rational.

What is your best bet? Explain.

Thank you so much!

Comment: The first part tells you that the size of $\mathbb{Q}$ is less than 1, and the next part tells you that it is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: The idea is that you can fit all the rationals into a collection of intervals whose combined length is arbitrarily small. In this sense, the rationals don't take up any space in the real line

Comment: For my own education of SE norms, could someone explain why this was downvoted? Was it the "Please help!" part? Because the question was well posed, written with great MathJAX, with work showing the OP's answer, which was correct - the OP just didn't understand how the algebraic answer related to a geometric size.

Comment: It should be $1/2^n$ not $1/2n$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the feedback. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental thing to realize in the first part is that you’ve covered all the rationals with segments totaling a length of $1,$ but there is no way to cover the entire real line with intervals that  $1.$

(That part - that you can’t cover the whole real line similarly - requires proof, but for now, treat it as intuitive that if you cover the entire real line with countably many intervals,  the sum of the lengths will be infinite.)

The $\epsilon$ part shows that you can make the covering intervals for the rationals have a total length as small as you want. When you get to it, this means that the “outer measure” of the rationals, or any countable subset of the rationals, is zero.

You can apply a similar approach to the dart board example. Given a cover of the rational points on the board by rectangles, the probability that $P$ is rational in both coordinates is less than or equal to the sum of the areas of the rectangles. Since you can make the sum of the areas as small as you want, the probability is zero.

It takes a little more to show that the probability of one coordinate being rational is also zero.

Mathematicians like to use “almost sure” for things that have probability $1.$ Here, it is almost sure that the coordinates of $P$ are both irrational.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Andrews, can you please explain why the probability of one coordinate being rational is also zero? Thank you so much!